# How to run a partial correlation analysis with ID as factor?

Tags: r, partial-correlation

I want to make a within-individual correlation between several molecules and molecule X in a repeated measure design, there are 8 measurements per individual. If I have understood this correctly I should run a partial correlation analysis with ID as factor.

```
The r package I found is:
pcor.test(x, y, z, use = c("mat","rec"), method = c("pearson","spearman","kendall"), na.rm = T)
```

so I want to compare x to each molecule and adjust for all other molecules. In the same time ID should be a factor. Should I use another packages? or how to include id in the code?

Appreciate suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "actually do"?

Comment: @whuber question is updated:)